# Why Loops with one basic instruction works in O(1)

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

Why C++ compiler executes this code very fast? as if it's one statement.

```
long long sum = 0;
for (long long i = 1; i <= 100000000000; i++)
    sum ++;
cout << sum;
```

It seems like compilers optimize it as sum += 100000000000. so how? and what's the limitation of this?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 5.3.0

Comment: Yes, GCC will do this [at -O1](https://godbolt.org/g/P2W5iM).

Comment: VC++ produces SIMD instructions to execute that code and will loop your code to produce that output. That's another reason to switch to a better compiler.

Comment: @Asesh My experiment shows the contrary. https://godbolt.org/g/rcu7Jn

Comment: @NickyC I tried that code in VC++ 2015 (Release version). Good to know that it has been improved